# Stripe Integration Problems

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm integrating stripe to a project for school. I've gone through the docs and followed their instructions. I'm getting a POST 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) and a Error fetching payment intent: Error: Failed to fetch payment intent at App.js.70:1 I've read and reread stripe's docs, spoken to my instructor, asked chatgpt, and reached out to their customer support. (haven't heard back from them yet, but I have a deadline for my project so I'm not sure if they'll get back to me in time.) What am I doing wrong?

Here is my create-payment-intent:

```
load_dotenv()
stripe_keys = {
    "secret_key": os.environ["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"],
    "publishable_key": os.environ["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"],
}

stripe.api_key = stripe_keys["secret_key"]

class OrderItems(Resource):
    def get(self):
        order_items = [order_item.to_dict() for order_item in OrderItem.query.all()]
        return make_response(order_items, 200)

    def post(self):
        req_json = request.get_json()
        print(req_json)

        try:
            sku_id = req_json['sku_id']
            order_id = req_json['order_id']
            quantity = req_json['quantity']

            new_order_item = OrderItem(
                sku_id = sku_id,
                order_id = order_id,
                quantity=quantity,
            )

            db.session.add(new_order_item)
            db.session.commit()

            return make_response(new_order_item.to_dict(), 201)
        
        except KeyError as e:
            missing_field = str(e)
            print(f"keyError: {missing_field}")
            return {'error': f'Missing required field: {missing_field}'}, 400
        except IntegrityError:
            return {'error': 'Database integrity violation'}, 500

        
@app.route('/create-payment-intent', methods=['POST'])
def create_payment():
        try:
            # Setup env vars beforehand 
            stripe_keys = {
                "secret_key": os.environ["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"],
                "publishable_key": os.environ["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"],
            }

            stripe.api_key = stripe_keys["secret_key"]
            data = request.get_json()

            if 'customer' not in data:
                return jsonify(error='Invalid request: Missing "customer" key'), 400
            
            print(f"Request Data: {request.data}")

            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=2000,
                currency='usd',
                automatic_payment_methods=['card'],
                metadata={
                    'customer': data['customer']
                },
            )

            # return jsonify({'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']}), 200
            return make_response(jsonify({'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']}), 200)

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            print(f"Stripe Error creating payment intent: {error_message}")
            return jsonify(error=f'Stripe Error: {error_message}'), 500

        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            print(f"Error creating payment intent: {error_message}")
            return jsonify(error=f'Failed to create payment intent: {error_message}'), 500
```

And my App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { CustomerAuthContext } from "../context/CustomerAuthProvider";
import Home from './Home';
import Profile from './Profile';
import Shop from './Shop';
import Leather from './Leather';
import Story from "./Story";
import Donation from "./Donation";
import FAQs from "./FAQs";
import ProductDetail from "./ProductDetail"
import Cart from "./Cart";
import About from "./About"
import Header from "./Header"; 
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import CheckoutForm from './CheckoutForm';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  #this is where i put my publishable key
);

function App() {
  const { checkAuthorized, customer } = useContext(CustomerAuthContext);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("")
  const [order_items, setOrder_items] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthorized();

    fetchOrderItems();
  }, [])

  function fetchOrderItems() {

    fetch('/order_items')
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch order items");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setOrder_items(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching order items:", error);
      });
  }

  function loadIntent() {

    if (!order_items) {
      console.error("Order is not defined.");
      return;
    }

    const order_itemIds = order_items.map((order_item) => order_item.sku_id);
    console.log(order_itemIds)

        fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({ items: order_itemIds, customer: customer.id }),
        })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error("Failed to fetch payment intent");
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log("Stripe API: response:", data);
            setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching payment intent:", error);

          if (error.response) {
            console.error("Response Status:", error.response.status);
            error.response.text().then((text) => {
              console.error("Response Body:", text);
            });
            console.error("Stripe API response:", error.response);
          }
          });
        }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (customer) {
      loadIntent()}
  }, [customer, order_items])

  const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe',
  };
  
  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance,
  };


  return (
  <div>
    <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/customer/:id" ><Profile /></Route>
        <Route path="/about"><About /></Route>
        <Route path="/shop" ><Shop /></Route>         
        <Route path="/leather" ><Leather /></Route>        
        <Route path="/story" ><Story /></Route>
        <Route path="/donation"><Donation /></Route>
        <Route path="/faqs"><FAQs /></Route>
        <Route path="/products/:id"><ProductDetail /></Route>
        <Route path="/products"></Route>
        <Route path="/cart"><Cart /></Route>
        <Route path="/checkout">
          {clientSecret && (
            <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
              <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>
          )}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/"><Home /></Route>
      </Switch>
    <Footer />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here and it is difficult to clearly understand exactly where the 500 error is being thrown.  Could you add some additional details walking through exactly what the code execution path is and what line throws this error?

Comment: there are numerous undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In your server endpoint, `automatic_payment_methods=['card']` isn't a thing, it should be either:
-`payment_method_types=['card']`
-`automatic_payment_methods={'enabled':True}`

Comment: I have changed it to 'enabled': True. Still not working.

Comment: For some reason when I opened it up this morning the checkout page loaded for the first time. Even though I hadn't made any changes. Now I'm getting an error:      
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3NuMZEAon7k0RE4W0o4mm2FO/confirm 400 when I try to submit payment

Comment: That error suggests you're trying to confirm the Payment Intent with a GET request instead of a POST. Being honest, I don't recognize any of the React / frontend code with what Stripe documents for this confirmation: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements&client=react#web-submit-payment